# How to block the client action of the iframe in mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, client

In mobile browser if i click the iframe it will give some border color it means its selected ifram. so how do i block the client side selection in the browser.

Comment: perhaps `iframe onfocus="this.blur()"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way, save below code as .html and then try in browser:

```
<div style="position:relative">
   <div style="width:300px;height:300px;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;z-index:1;"><br /><br /><br />World~~~~~</div>
   <div style="width:300px;height:300px;position:absolute;left:0;top:0">Hello (put your iframe here, you could not select the text in this DIV)</div>
</div>
```